# nginx server using multiple fastcgi backends for different subfolders

Tags: nginx, configuration, fastcgi, nginx-location

there are multiple questions on StackOverflow how to use subfolders with different fastcgi backends or questions similar but nothing is working correct - and after hours of trying and reading the documentation (maybe missing a small detail) i am giving up.

I have the following requirements:

- on `/` a php 5.6 application is running (fastcgi backend `127.0.0.1:9000`)
- on `/crm` a php 7.0 application is running which has to believe it's running on `/` (fastcgi backend `127.0.0.1:9001`)
- *infact there are few more backends, but with these two i can make them by my own*

I tried defining separate php contexts for location prefixes first, before trying to remove `/crm` prefix. But it seems i am doing something wrong because `/crm` is everytime using the php context of `/`.

My actual stripped-down configuration, removed everything not relevant and all failed tests:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.localdev;

    location /crm {
        root       /var/www/crm/public;
        index      index.php;
        try_files  $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            # todo: strip /crm from REQUEST_URI
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001; # 9001 = PHP 7.0
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location / {
        root       /var/www/intranet;
        index      index.php;
        try_files  $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000; # 9000 = PHP 5.6
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer you want - but I wrote about a similar problem [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/766222/nginx-reverse-proxy-making-root-webapp-into-custom-path/766225#766225)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's not the same problem. Your 3rd problem, which is the only thing that couldn't be solved can be easily solved for us by using the html base tag for the crm application.

Comment: You have a couple of `;` missing, and the default action on one of your `try_files` is wrong. Is that the problem? That `/crm` is going to `/index.php` rather than `/crm/index.php`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two minor errors in your config:

1. The last argument of `try_files` is an internal redirect when none of the files before could be found. That means that for the CRM location you want to set it to `try_files  $uri /crm/index.php$is_args$args;`
2. You have to strip `/crm` from the `$fastcgi_script_name`. The recommended way of doing it is to use `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/crm\/)(.+\.php)(.*)$;`

A possibly working config would look like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.localdev;

    location /crm {
        root       /var/www/crm/public;
        index      index.php;
        try_files  $uri /crm/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            # todo: strip /crm from REQUEST_URI
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001; # 9001 = PHP 7.0

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/crm\/)(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location / {
        root       /var/www/intranet;
        index      index.php;
        try_files  $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000; # 9000 = PHP 5.6
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work. "Maybe", it's quite complicated to test, as it has to be done on one of the production servers, the development machines have only a subset of the installed software. Is there a possibility to have `/crm` routed to the same `root` but with a different php version? Would make testing much more simpler (simply test phpinfo output).

Comment: Of course, just configure the /crm location to use the same root and you are good to go. The way /phpinfo.php will use PHP 5.6, and /crm/phpinfo.php will use 7.0.

Comment: I have not yet succeeded in using the configuration but it looks the most promising. You'll get the bounty. Maybe i'll ask something in a few days, too much work this week.

Answer (score 0):

Running this on Ubuntu 14.04 and Nginx 1.10.

You can try to specify the socket.

PHP7

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

Note: The path of the PHP7 socket is the "same" as PHP5. It's not */var/run/php7-fpm.sock*. I stumbled into some articles that indicated this as the default path. Please check how it's installed on your server.

PHP5

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

Also, running PHP7, you might encounter a *Permission Denied* error. This problem can be due to a user issue in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. Where in the PHP7 config user/group are `www-data` while Nginx user is `nginx`.

This is the PHP7 config:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

In my case, I changed the Nginx user to *www-data*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is not defining the socket or "Permission Denied" errors. The routing of specific folders to specific php configurations is the problem.